# By running client-side queries on a SQL Server Express database, does that mitigate the 1 GB memory limit?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API with a SQL Server Express database running on a 4-core, 8 GB VPS. SQL Server Express edition is limited to 1 GB memory.

Would it be more performant to run complex queries / joins on the database OR run basic queries on the database and run the complex queries on the dataset that is returned to the .net app via LINQ etc?

Given that the .NET app would not have the memory or CPU limitations that SQL Server has.

DB and the Web API are on the same VPS so network shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I guess you'd just have to try and measure - it's extremely hard to make any predictions, not knowing **anything** about how your data looks like, and how much data we're talking about here.....

Comment: There is no way to answer that question in the general sense because it depends on what the complex queries are doing, how much data is involved and how it is structured, and whether you will be able to write better solutions client-side than what the database people were able to write. In the general sense, I think the closest answer you can get is that it will probably be better to run them client-side. You will just have to try it and see.